# problems with creating bash script with sed script

Tags: shell-script, sed, echo

So, when i am creating file in my Docker manifesto with `echo`:

```
RUN \
echo "#!/bin/bash\n\
mounted_tz=$(cat /etc/timezone)\n\
sed -i -r \"s~^(log_timezone\s*=\s*).*$~\1\'\$mounted_tz\'~\" /etc/postgresql/9.6/main/postgresql.conf\n\
sed -i -r \"s~^(timezone\s*=\s*).*$~\1\'\$mounted_tz\'~\" /etc/postgresql/9.6/main/postgresql.conf\n" > /root/pgtz-updaters; \
```

and then open this file in created container, i see this:

```
#!/bin/bash
mounted_tz=Etc/UTC
sed -i -r "s~^(log_timezone\s*=\s*).*$~^A\'$mounted_tz\'~" /etc/postgresql/9.6/main/postgresql.conf
sed -i -r "s~^(timezone\s*=\s*).*$~^A\'$mounted_tz\'~" /etc/postgresql/9.6/main/postgresql.conf
```

How could i make echo not to decode this character into this?

Comment: Use single quotes instead of double quotes, or backslashes before dollars. See the [Bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Quoting.html#Quoting).

Comment: Why on earth are you doing this? Why not just write the bash script in a file and then use a `COPY` directive in your Dockerfile to add the script to the container? It will have the same effect, except it will be much easier....

Comment: @Z4-tier i wouldn't post the question, if i didn't want to keep one-line scripts in docker project

Comment: @berndbausch it doesn't matter what kind of quotes you use here - it still decoding

Comment: I am not sure about the subtleties of `RUN` processing. Perhaps you need to quote twice?  To avoid getting entangled in quoting, I agree with @Z4-tier - use COPY or ADD. The RUN command is already unreadable as it is; correct quoting will make that worse.